# Jquery inview element should work on load and on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to make this inview function working by adding a class to the element and remove it when not inview.
Not sure what I'm missing... any help please?

http://jsfiddle.net/zefjh/

```
$.fn.isOnScreen = function () {

    var win = $(window);

    var viewport = {
        top: win.scrollTop(),
        left: win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
};

$('.box').click(function () {
    alert($('.box').isOnScreen());
});

if ($('.box').isOnScreen() == true) {
    $('.box').addClass('inview');
}
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($('.box').isOnScreen() == true) {
        $('.box').addClass('inview');
    } else {
        $('.box').removeClass('inview');
    }
});
```

Comment: This might be of interest to you: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport The plugin is very small and should be easy to extract what you need from it: https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_viewport/blob/master/jquery.viewport.js

Comment: your function always returns true on scroll

Comment: @K.K.Agarwal yes I noticed not sure why! could u help?

Comment: @@user3699998 - check the fiddle .. http://jsfiddle.net/kka284556/zefjh/4/ do you want like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$.each` to check every `.box`, whether It's on screen or not, on scroll.

`$.each($(".box"), function(){
            if ($(this).isOnScreen()) {
                 $(this).addClass('inview');
            }

            else{
                $(this).removeClass('inview');
            }
        });`

Also: Your click function should check If the clicked element is on screen using `this`

`$('.box').click(function(){
    alert($(this).isOnScreen());
});`

And finally: You can leave the `== true` part in your if statements.

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/zefjh/2/

Comment: Thanks dude I thought to use $each too... thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

I modified your function at fiddle just check it

```
fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kka284556/zefjh/4/
```

I made it on scroll

Comment: doesn't do the job as the class should be added when the element shows up

Comment: Yes, but trick was adding the $each, so it was going to check all elements (.box)

Comment: I checked your fiddle, the `.box` which Is on screen Is the only div that doesn't have a class `.inview`. It should be the other way round. Your click function doesn't work correctly either, It sometimes returns false while the clicked `.box` is partially on screen and thus should return true.